# Exposing "Undo" in FlutterFlowSwipeableStack using a custom action

Tags: flutter, dart, flutterflow

I would like to "undo" a swipe in FlutterFlowSwipeableStack and return to the previously swiped card.  I see no way to do directly accomplish this in the UI.

Digging deeper, it appears that FlutterFlowSwipeableStack is a thin wrapper around `flutter_card_swiper.dart`.  The underlying CardSwiper class has an undo() method but this does not seem to be exposed in the FlutterFlow generated `flutter_flow_swipeable_stack.dart`

The CardSwipeController is an attribute (`.controller`) of the FlutterFlowSwipeableStack.  I was hoping I could create a custom action to access this and trigger the "undo" method.  However, despite numerous attempts, I can't figure out how to use the passed BuildContext to access the widget and the controller attribute.